# How to change Import path specific to src folder in react?

Tags: reactjs, import, eslint

I have this type of absolute imports in my code I have this
`import { getProjectById } from 'utils/api/projectServices`
and i want it like this

```
import { getProjectById } from 'src/utils/api/projectServices'
```

for this i have done change in my jscofig.json file, below is my jsconfig.json file :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

By using this file i am getting error for Import not Found ,and when i change the path and include src to the path, it is working, How can i fix all of the imports automatically to include src in the path?